# Attempting to host simple html page on apache tomcat

Tags: apache-http-server

I have an html page that loads fine when opened in a browser, but I want to host it on my apache tomcat server (temporarily).  And I can't seem to get this to work, every attempt at using the url `localhost:8080/webapps/main.html` gives me a 404 error.

Very very simple question I'm guessing, just at a loss as to why.  Been a while since I played around with hosting though.

Answer (score 1):

use the command

```
netstat -an | find "8080"
```

in terminal to find whether the port 8080 is listening.

Then try with the url "localhost:8080/main.html" without webapps

hope this helps!